# Make each individual feature layer based on list of OBJECTID with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, split-by-attribute

I want to make each separate individual feature layer based on list of OBJECTID of one feature layer. And I want the name of each feature layer to be sequential (e.g.: 1, 2, 3, 4..)

So far I already have this:

```
list_a = []
a = ''    
selection = 0
selection = len(arcpy.Describe(fc).FIDSet)
if selection < 0:
    sys.exit

rows = arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc, 'OBJECTID')
for row in rows:
    list_a.append(row[0])
    a = a + str(row[0]) + ';'

for OID in a:
    fc_i = "Feature Class {}".format(OID)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_path, fc_i, "OBJECTID = " + str(OID))
```

I get the error of this:

```
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7682, in MakeFeatureLayer
    raise e
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7679, in MakeFeatureLayer
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.MakeFeatureLayer_management(*gp_fixargs((in_features, out_layer, where_clause, workspace, field_info), True)))
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 511, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError:
```

Do you have a solution for this problem? Also the I still haven't figured out how to make the feature layers name to be Feature Class 1, Feature Class 2, Feature Class 3,...

Comment: Is there more of the error message? Does the field OBJECTID exist? If it's a shapefile the OIDField is FID and it's dangerous to use in this manner. From a describe object, created by a describe statement you can get OIDFieldName https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Table_properties/03q300000050000000/ to be sure the field exists.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/279721/115